# existence and uniqueness of 1st ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find an interval in which

$ty'+2y=4t^2$

$y(1)=2$

$f$ is continuous on  $t\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}, y\in \mathbb{R}$

$\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} $  is continuous on $t\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$

hence, we guarantee the existence of a solution in the region t>0.

What about the region t<0? can we still have a solution there, although the initial condition does not reside there?

Comment: Yes.
Multiply the ODE by -1. Solve again for $ t>0$ and the solution will be existing and unique for the new O.D.E and equiv for the old one on  $t<0$

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by $f$. Your differential equation is easily solved by multiplying with $t$. The result is $y(t)=({t^4}+1)/{t^4}$, valid for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are both continuous for $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ only implies that there exists a unique solution for some interval around any initial point in this range, not that there exists a unique solution over this entire range.

The usual way to approach such problems is to look at a triangle around your initial point of the form $[_0-a,t_0+a]\times[y_0-b,y_0+b]$, a unique solution can be shown to exist in an interval $[t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha]$ with $\alpha=\min\{a,\frac{b}{M}\}$, where $M$ is a bound on $f$ in the given rectangle.

In your particular case we can take $a=b=\frac1 2 $ (for example), and find $M=8$ (after a bit of tedious analysis) from which you can deduce $\alpha=\min\{\frac1 2,\frac1 2/8\}=\frac{1}{16}$, so a solution is guaranteed to exist for $t\in[1-\frac1{16},1+\frac1{16}]$.

Note that you can probably optimize the choice of $a$ and $b$ to obtain a larger interval.